# Scalar product $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=ab\cos \vartheta$ is it a definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vectors

Two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with components $a_x$ and $a_y$ (respectively $b_x$ and $b_y$), along the $x$ and $y$ axes can be written as:

$$\mathbf{a}=a_x\hat{\bf x}+a_x\hat{\bf y}, \quad \mathbf{b}=b_x\hat{\bf x}+b_x\hat{\bf y} $$

In several books in Italian language the $(1)$ is taken as definition of scalar product which has commutative property:

$$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}ab\cos \vartheta \tag{1}$$
where $\vartheta=\measuredangle \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}$. For my humble opinion it is not properly correct because to exist this simple proof:

$$\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=a_xb_x+a_yb_y=a\cos\vartheta_a \ b\cos\vartheta_b+a\sin\vartheta_a \ b\sin \vartheta_a$$
$$=ab \ (\cos\vartheta_a\cos\vartheta_b+\sin\vartheta_a\sin\vartheta_a)=ab \ \cos (\vartheta_a - \vartheta_b)$$
$$=ab \cos \vartheta \tag{2}$$

where $\vartheta_a$ is the angle measured in the counterclockwise direction in relation to the $x-$axis; same for $\vartheta_b$. In addition let be $\vartheta_a>\vartheta_b$ and $\vartheta=\vartheta_a-\vartheta_b>0$.

My clarifications are two:

1. What is the correct definition of scalar product $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=a_xb_x+a_yb_y \,$ or $\, \mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=ab\cos \vartheta$?
2. Is there a different proof of the $(2)$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps or whether this is what you are unsure about, but the commutative property holds because the cosine function is even.  If a rotation from $\vec{a}$ to $\vec{b}$ is $\theta$, then the rotation from $\vec{b}$ to $\vec{a}$ is $-\theta$, and we know that $\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$.

Comment: @AndrewChin Yes of course :-). The scalar product is commutative. I can use the clockwise or anticlockwise because $\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume vectors are column vectors, unless transposed. I recommend the definition $a\cdot b=\sum_ia_ib_i$, the unique entry in the $1\times 1$ matrix $a^Tb$ (so $a^T$ is a row vector), since then it's obvious $a\cdot b$ is invariant under rotations [viz.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.) $a\mapsto Ra,\,b\mapsto Rb$ with $R^TR$ the identity matrix so that$$(Ra)^TRb=a^TR^TRb=a^Tb\implies (Ra)\cdot Rb=a\cdot b.$$Since $ab\cos\vartheta$ (I usually see $\theta$ used, but maybe that's an English thing) is also obviously invariant under rotations, to prove the two expressions for $a\cdot b$ are equivalent you can start by rotating so $a$ is along the positive $x$-axis. Then$$\hat{x}\cdot\hat{x}=1,\,\hat{x}\cdot\hat{y}=0\implies a\cdot b=(a\hat{x})\cdot(b\cos\vartheta\hat{x}+b\sin\vartheta\hat{y})=ab\cos\vartheta.$$

Comment: I prefer :-) stylistically $\vartheta$ but usually it is used $\theta$. What does "viz" mean? And what do you mean with $\mathbf{a}^\intercal$: row vector or column vector? Can you, please, explain better $a↦Ra,b↦Rb$ with $R^TR$ the identity matrix? Thank you and +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano I've edited my answer to address those questions.

Comment: It was a Latin term :-( which I didn't know. I'm so sorry. Your answer has been definitively approved and I apologize for my trivial question but I try to do my best for my students. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano No problem. I just really like using that particular term. It's one of those technically Latin expressions that's just seeped into English, albeit not in a way most speakers know outside mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer covers it, but here's another way that avoids rotations and such. It's just a straight calculation: note that for any $v\in \mathbb R^n,\ v\cdot v=\|v\|^2.$ Then, expanding and using the law of cosines,

$ \| a^2\| + \|b \|^2 - 2 a \cdot b=\|a-b\|^2= \| a^2\| + \|b \|^2-2 \|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta\Rightarrow a \cdot b=\|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta.$

Comment: In the meantime, thank you for giving me another chance to prove the scalar product. If you look at my profile I am a humble high school teacher and unfortunately with so much sadness the norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not on the programme. I welcome your answer.

Comment: in $\mathbb R^2$, the norm is just the distance formula and the law of cosines is just basic trig. Should be accessible to you students!

Comment: Yes, of course :-), but I can not use the symbol $||\cdot||$.